ASP.NET Core Negotiate authentication and Firefox
I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API that is self-hosted in Kestrel, and uses Negotiate Authentication via the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate package.
The authentication flow works perfectly fine with Chrome and Edge, but not with Firefox. In particular, with Firefox I don't even see the popup that asks for the user credentials, the call just fails with error 401, as shown here:

Searching online, I've found out that you should set some advanced options to make this work on Firefox, so I set them like this:

(I had to censor the domain names for privacy reasons, but they're just the two domains where I need this to work, in comma-separated format)
What am I missing or doing wrong? Feel free to ask for further details if it can help, I don't exactly know what else to include...

Kestrel both support Kerberos and NTLM , you might check it. By the way, if it's using Kerberos, we need to set network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris and network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris, if we are using NTML we need to set network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris. I trust you can also find related information too. I'm afraid it's due to missing configuration or failed to apply. Maybe a restart is deserved to try. Thanks for your test result: )

@TinyWang: thanks for the suggestion, should I put the domain(s) in these properties or complete URIs (with protocol/port etc.)?

Domain, I remembered that one of the searching result pointed me to set domain instead of complete url. like example.com I didn't test that, so that could you pls help test it? Thanks a lot.
